# In Haskell, what is the most straightforward way to take roots of real numbers?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to take the cube root of a number in Haskell (GHCi, actually). In something like Java, I'd just do `Math.Pow( x, 1.0/3.0)` and move on, but I don't see a way to do that so easily in Haskell.

So, is there some simple idiom for taking arbitrary roots of arbitrary real numbers?

Comment: What's wrong with `x ** (1.0/3.0)`?

Comment: @jwodder: make that `x ** (1/3)`, there's no good reason to add decimal zeroes in Haskell. Even better: `x**recip 3`, for that matter.

Comment: I like using decimal zeros for clarity. But that is subjective, of course.

Comment: Ah. Beautiful. I was using (^) and failing. Didn't realize there are TWO exponentiation operators. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnL4 Well, you didn't realize there were two operators for good reason: there are actually *three*! Add the smily `(^^)` to your mix. =)

Comment: @hugomg The "problem" with adding the zeros is that you are adding an implicit `Fractional` constraint which may not be required.

Comment: @Bakuriu: the `Fractional` constraint _is_ certainly required if you use `/` to generate the fractional exponents... and it's also superclass of `Floating`, which you need for `**`. — The reason I don't like writing `1.0` is that it kinda suggests the literal is “precise to one significant digit after the decimal point”, which doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, but what if you have `x.0/y` and after some time change it to `x.0*y`?

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, there is no function to compute nth-roots in the standard library. However you could just use the same pow method from Java

```
nroot :: Floating a => Int -> a -> a
nroot n x = x ** (1.0 / fromIntegral n)
```

Or even more idiomatically:

```
nroot n x = x ** recip n
```

example:

```
nroot 4 81.0  -- returns 3.0
```

The `**` operator is the equivalent of Java's `Math.pow`and the `fromIntegral` is required to cast n from an int to a floating point value